# Node.js read src value from html and get images

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, pug

I am developing a small app (playing around to upgrade my skills) to build static websites using Node.js, Express and Gulp.
The app consist of PUG template engine to build HTML and an Asset folder, where all my static files resides (images, css, js).

The images folder has a lot of images init and we are not necessarily using all of them. 
However, what I want to do is;

1. To be able to read in the html file (index.html)
2. Retrieve the path of images
3. Fetch images that are being used from the asset directory
4. Copy images and create another structure in destination folder with
   the index.html and images
5. Zip the final output folder the of website if possible.

**Below is a structure of the app.**

```
|- Battlefield
  |- app
    |- Assets
      |- images
    |- Views
      |- html
        |- index.html
      |- pug
        |- index.pug
  |- dest
```

**Here is my Gulpfile.js**

```js
// Requiring Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var pug = require('gulp-pug');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('hello', function() {
  //Test Gulp task 'hello'
  console.log('Hello Zell');
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/Assets/scss/**/*.scss') // Gets all files ending with .scss in app/scss and children dirs
    .pipe(sass()) //using gulp-sass
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/Assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});


gulp.task('pug', /*['copy'],*/ function() {
  return gulp.src('app/Views/pug/**/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({
      pretty: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/Views/html'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});


// Multiple watch process
gulp.task('watch', ['browserSync', 'sass', 'pug'], function() {
  gulp.watch('app/Assets/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('app/Views/pug/**/*.pug', ['pug']);
  // Reloads the browser whenever HTML or CSS or JS files change
  gulp.watch('app/Views/html/*.html', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/Assets/css/**/*.css', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('app/Assets/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('browserSync', ['nodemon'], function() {
  browserSync.init(null, {
    proxy: "http://localhost:4000",
    files: ["app/**/*.*"],
    port: 7000,
  });
});

gulp.task('nodemon', function(cb) {

  var started = false;

  return nodemon({
    script: 'server.js'
  }).on('start', function() {
    // to avoid nodemon being started multiple times
    // thanks github user @matthisk
    if (!started) {
      cb();
      started = true;
    }
  });
});
```

**Updates:**

Here under is package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Framework",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Aumeeruddy Ajmal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-pug": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

For example I have the following HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Node Static files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/main.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="images/example.jpg" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

And I want node or gulp, via a command or task, to be able to read that html, find the `<img src="..." alt="">` section, retrieve the path of the image.
Look into the path directory and copy the image to another directory (for restructuring) and then zip the output package.

Comment: "To be able to read in the html file (index.html)" What do you mean? When browserSync started then index.html viewed first? Right?

Comment: Hi @HaHuuTin,

Thanks for your reply. I updated the question to be more precise.

I hope you are getting the picture.
Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks,
Ajmal

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch updated assets and html files you could use these 2 packages  to achieve what you need. If you update to gulp4, you can have some pretty nifty features that can help you out.

All your answers for gulp can be found here : https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/4.0#sample-gulpfilejs

**A note about Express**

Because Express is an HTTP server, you construct your own routes to any files/assets you want to serve.
So for example images will have their URLs set in this manner in a custom express config file: img src='/layout/*.png'

My config, if that can help you out :

'use strict';

const express = require('express'),

```
path = require('path'),

favicon = require('serve-favicon'),

serve_static = require('serve-static'),

cookie_parser = require('cookie-parser'),

body_parser = require('body-parser'),

http = require('http');
```

module.exports = (app, config)=> {

```
app.set('port', 4000);
app.set('views', './server/views/pages/');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(cookie_parser());
app.use(body_parser.json());
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use('/stylesheets', express.static('./builds/app/stylesheets'));
app.use('/scripts', express.static('./builds/app/scripts'));
app.use('/fonts', express.static('./builds/app/fonts'));
app.use('/images', express.static('./builds/app/images'));
```

}

However, if you are maintaining a solution and you need to have the compiled html sources along the other assets delivered to another party, i would suggest you to use this gulp package, which would rewrite the paths of the assets(strin replacement) in your html, css files to another source you prefer.
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace

Comment: Gulp version: 3.9.0. I update question with my package.json.